# Proving that a numbers puzzle on Countdown is impossible

Tags: number-theory

For [Countdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_(game_show)#Numbers_round) (a British quiz show), is there any way we can prove a numbers game is impossible?

Comment: Exhaustive search - there are only a finite number of options, so the full set of possible calculations can be enumerated. Beyond that, though, this problem is likely to be formally hard - it's a very close cousin to things like subset-sum problems that are known to be NP-complete.  This means that a truly 'efficient' algorithm for the problem is highly unlikely.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering if something like this link could be done for it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZR2ND4l_5Y

Comment: Not in any succinct form - that question is innately 'one-dimensional' in a way, because we're evaluating a polynomial in one variable; the Countdown question is innately multi-dimensional, because _all_ of the numbers are available as arguments.

Comment: I don't have a mathematical answer but I do have an script which checks every possible combination of math ops across all the numbers until the target appears, or it returns nothing if no solution can be found. I can show it to you if you still want (javascript/ts)... 6 years later